# List<Integer> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, list, typeconverter

At the beginning of my code, there is:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList();
```

And then, (here is to reverse a sub-list):

```
List<Integer> sub = new ArrayList();
re = reverse(result.get(j)); // error occurs here
```

There is this method:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> reverse(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=list.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        newList.add(list.get(i));}
        return newList;
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> List cannot be converted to ArrayList

Why?

Comment: How is `re` declared?  Keep in mind that a `List` isn't an `ArrayList`, but the opposite is quite true.

Comment: List it is interface, ArrayList it is one the classes, that implements the List interface. So, any ArrayList is List (i.e. ArrayList could be implicitly assigned to List), but not vice-versa. Either change return type to List<Integeer>, or change newList variable type to ArrayList<Integer>. By the way, move "return" out of the loop body.

Comment: Don't use the raw type `ArrayList`. Use `new ArrayList<>();` instead of `new ArrayList();`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think of it like this, you have a `Fruit` called `re` (I use this name because it's the name of the variable you are using).

```
Fruit re;
```

You have a method `reverse` whose input type is `Apple`.

```
public Apple reverse(Apple a) {
    // ...
}
```

We have a variable `re` that we declared as `Fruit` which means we're saying it's always going to be some kind of `Fruit`, perhaps `Apple`, but maybe `Orange` -- or even `Banana`.

When you try to give the `Fruit` to the method taking `Apple` the compiler stops you, because it can't be certain that it's 100% an `Apple`. For example...

```
Fruit re = new Orange();
reverse(re);
```

Yikes! We are putting a square peg into a round hole so to speak. `reverse` takes `Apple`, not `Orange`. Bad things could happen!

> **Side note:** Why is it okay then to assign `Apple` to something declared as `Fruit` then? (`reverse` returns an `Apple`, `Fruit f = reverse(re);` is legal.) Because an `Apple` *is* a `Fruit`. If it were declared as the more specific `Apple` and the return type were the more general `Fruit`, *then* there would be an issue here. (If `reverse` returned `Fruit`, `Apple a = reverse(re);` would be illegal.)

***If you didn't follow the metaphor,*** replace `Fruit` with `List` and `Apple` with `ArrayList` and read the above again. `List` is `Fruit`, a general way to describe an abstract idea. `ArrayList` is `Apple`, a specific implementation of the abstract idea. (`LinkedList` could be `Orange` too.)

In general you want to declare things as the most general thing you can to get the functionality you need. Making the below change should fix your problem.

```
public List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> list) {
```

We are taking some kind of `List` of `Integer`s and returning some kind of `List` of `Integer`s.

Comment: Oh, ok. I see. Thank you very much! I like your cute example!

Answer (score 10):

You're using a specific implementation of the `List` interface as a return type for the `reverse` function (namely `ArrayList`). This forces what you return to be an `ArrayList`, but you're defining it as `List`.

To understand, try and change the construction part to use a `LinkedList`, which also implements `List`:

```
List<Integer> newList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

This construction is valid, but now we try and return a `LinkedList` from a function that returns an `ArrayList`. This makes no sense since they aren't related (But notice this: they both implement `List`).

So now you have two options:

Make the implementation more specific by forcing use of `ArrayList`s:

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or **better**, make the implementation more general by changing the function's return type (any `List` can be plugged in):

```
public List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> list){
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very useful!

Answer (score 2):

It's because your result varible has a type of List, but your method want an ArrayList
Try it with:

```
List<ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

**or** change your function in:

```
public List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> list){...
```

Comment: OK. Got it. Thank you for your very simple but clear answer!